# validationEngine grouprequired AND custom

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

am using posabs validationEngine,
and want to validate a group then validate a UK phone number on the item
completed within the group
so - have three textboxes with group called "phone"

```
      data-validation-engine="validate[groupRequired[phone], custom[ukPhoneNumber]]"
```

and a custom rule

```
"ukPhoneNumber": { "regex": /^[0-9]{11}$/,
               "alertText": "Must be a full UK phone number - no spaces",
               "alertText2": "Example: 01452123456 "
      },
```

when triggered the group rule works - but then the custom rule fires
requiring that all the text boxes have a phone number.
how would I make sure only one textbox is completed AND that only the one textbox
has a phonenumber?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone interested - added custom rule to jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
           "groupRequiredukphone": {
                "regex": /^[0-9]{11}$/,
                "alertText": "* You must have one valid phone number"
            },
```

and then edited jquery.validationEngine.js line 488

```
           case "groupRequired":
     case "groupRequiredukphone":
           etc.....
           break;
```

seems to-do the job